# How to change the color of text-field in vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to change the color of text-field in vuetify,I set the color but it doesn't work! Here is the result expected :[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hHR0.png)

Answer (score 0):

set `color` prop on the text-field.
Or, alternatively use `background-color`

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#api

example:

```
      <v-text-field
        label="My Lable"
        color="blue"
      ></v-text-field>
```